Retornar datos usando Laravel Inertia Vue3 sin usar redirect o back
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel-Inertia-Vue3. En este proyecto tengo un index de productos y en este index de productos tengo la opcion de poder realizar inserciones de nuevos productos. Para adicionar un producto uno de los datos a introducir es el brand del producto; este brand es un select donde el usuario debe seleccionar una opcion. Pero tengo el requisito que cuando se seleccione un brand automaticamente se ejecute una funcionalidad que usando el controller busque en la base de datos todos los productos que usan este brand y devuelva una serie de informaciones que se deben visualizar para el usuario (Cantidad de productos que usan el brand, cantidad total de dinero que representan todos los productos del brand. Hasta el momento la funcion que tengo implementada solo realiza la salva del nuevo producto y es la que pongo a continuacion:
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $product->description = $request->description;
    $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;

    if ($request->quantity > 0)
        $product->inStock = 1;

    $product->save();

    //check if product has images upload
    if ($request->hasFile('product_images')) {
        $productImages = $request->file('product_images');
        foreach ($productImages as $image) {
            // Generate a unique name for the image using timestamp and random string
            $uniqueName = time() . '-' . Str::random(10) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Store the image in the public folder with the unique name
            $image->move('product_images', $uniqueName);
            // Create a new product image record with the product_id and unique name
            ProductImage::create([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'image' => 'product_images/' . $uniqueName,
            ]);
        }
    }

  return redirect()->route('admin.products.index')->with('success', 'Product created successfully.')->with('prueba', 'Esto fue una prueba');
}

Pero me genera dudas como implementar una funcion extra que usando inertia no retorne un redirect o un back y me permita obtener la informacion desde el controller sin tener que redireccionar a la ruta del index de productos.
Alguna idea de como poder realizar esto?

Puedes usar un controlador separado para manejar la solicitud al seleccionar un brand, y devolver los datos en formato JSON para evitar redireccionamientos. Así:
public function getBrandInfo($brandId)
{
    $products = Product::where('brand_id', $brandId)->get();
    $totalProducts = $products->count();
    $totalValue = $products->sum('price');

    return response()->json([
        'totalProducts' => $totalProducts,
        'totalValue' => $totalValue
    ]);
}

Entonces, en tu componente Vue, haz una solicitud a esta ruta con axios al seleccionar el brand y actualiza los datos del frontend.
En el contexto de tu proyecto Laravel-Inertia-Vue3, axios se usaría para enviar una solicitud a tu controlador Laravel para obtener datos (como información del producto basada en la marca seleccionada) sin recargar la página.
